# I have array of objects and it needs to return array of sum based on condition

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects and it needs to return array of sum. if className.value identical then add Area.value values otherwise just return single value,

```js
    var obj = [{
        Area: {
          type: 'double',
          value: 150
        },
        className: {
          type: 'string',
          value: "gold"
        }
      },
      {
        Area: {
          type: 'double',
          value: 130
        },
        className: {
          type: 'string',
          value: "silver"
        }
      },
      {
        Area: {
          type: 'double',
          value: 250
        },
        className: {
          type: 'string',
          value: "gold"
        }
      },
    ];
    console.log(obj)

//expecting this array to return
console.log([400,130])
```

Comment: Best to give it a go yourself first and then post the code that you tried if you are stuck. You could create a function, pass in this object and return an array. The function will have the logic you are trying to create. A simple for loop or Array.forEach should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum up the values for the different classes. For this look with [Object#hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) if there is in the accumulator an property with the classname of the current object. If not so, so add one with this name (e.g. "gold") and add the value from the current object to this. Otherwise add to this property the value directly.
After the summation to this object with reduce I get with [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) the values from the Object as an array. At the end I just have to look if the array has only 1 entry. If so then return it as value otherwise return the array.

```js
function makeSum(arr) {
    let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        let classVal = cur.className.value;
        if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(classVal)) {
            acc[classVal] = cur.Area.value;
        } else {
            acc[classVal] += cur.Area.value;
        }
        return acc;
    },{}));
    
    if (result.length===1) result = result[0];
    
    return result;
}

let arr = [{ Area: { type: 'double', value: 150 }, className: { type: 'string', value: "gold" } }, { Area: { type: 'double', value: 130 }, className: { type: 'string', value: "silver" } }, { Area: { type: 'double', value: 250 }, className: { type: 'string', value: "gold" } }, ];
  
console.log(makeSum(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a `reduce` operation on the array, summing elements with the same `className.value` with an object.

```js
var obj = [{ Area: { type: 'double', value: 150 }, className: { type: 'string', value: "gold" } }, { Area: { type: 'double', value: 130 }, className: { type: 'string', value: "silver" } }, { Area: { type: 'double', value: 250 }, className: { type: 'string', value: "gold" } }, ];
const res = Object.values(
    obj.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
    acc[curr.className.value] = (acc[curr.className.value] || 0) + curr.Area.value;
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively just loop through the object and account for undefined. Use the className.value as element name to avoid duplicates.

```
function calculateValues(obj) {
  var output = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    output[obj[key].className.value] = (obj[key].className.value in output ? output[obj[key].className.value] : 0) + obj[key].Area.value;
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(calculateValues(obj));
```